# Solidity design pattern drawbacks

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, design-patterns

I was ask by a friend to give feedback on his solidity project. I came over a general design pattern issue, which is not good from an object oriented point of view. I try to outline the projects structure:

Think of a factory pattern like UniswapV2 with a factory, pairs and a router. In this scenario the user would interact mainly with the router which has a function to create a pair (by calling the factory internally). Besides creating and initializing the pair, the router stores many variables describing the pair, which should be directly in the pair. In Uniswap, the router would trigger the create function and stores mappings like (poolAddress => token0Address) and (poolAddress => reserves0) instead of storing token0Address and reserves0 directly in the Pair contract.
The original variables of my friend's file are describing the Pair, but the pair does not actually use this variables directly, thus it does not require the pair to call the router for some information. It completely wrong because he has many mappings inside the router which are like pairAddress => someInformationAboutThePair. If the router is called for a swapping functions, these variables are directly accessible and do not need an internal call to the pair contract. May that be even good?

I am now struggling with the explanation, why this approach is not good. Simple saying it is a bad design due to object oriented point of view seems a bit to easy and won't convince him to change it. Are there any other drawbacks maybe related to gas consumption in the described design.

I hope, the scenario is understandable and someone can help me out to make it clear, that this approach is not good for production.

Comment: Without looking at the exact code is hard to make a comment. The EVM is a restrictive environment so sometimes contract are designed to workaround some of the limitations, like contract size or gas consumption.